# Why is my CSS taking effect outside of my template?

Tags: html, web-component

I am importing a web component containing a template into `index.html`. Why is the style in `my-template` having an effect on the paragraph in `index.html`.

Put another way, why is all the text in `index.html` rendered as blue?

I thought CSS inside templates was namespaced in some way. Is this not the case?

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style> p { color: red; }</style>
        <link rel="import" href="my-component.html"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>FOO</p>
        <my-component></my-component>
    </body>
</html>
```

`my-component.html`

```
<template id="my-template">
    <style>
    p {
        color: blue;
    }
    </style>
    <p class="foo">BAR</p>
</template>
<script>
(function() {

    var importDoc, myComponentProto;

    importDoc = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;
    myComponentProto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

    myComponentProto.createdCallback = function() {
        var template1, template1Clone;

        template1 = importDoc.querySelector('#my-template');
        template1Clone = importDoc.importNode(template1.content, true);

        this.appendChild(template1Clone); // Insert into the DOM.
    };

    document.registerElement('my-component', {
        prototype: myComponentProto
    });

}())
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initially create shadow root to hide your template dom into shadow:

```
myComponentProto.createdCallback = function() {
  var shadow = this.createShadowRoot();
  shadow.appendChild(importDoc.querySelector('#my-template').content);
};
```

Live preview: http://plnkr.co/edit/QrvYEUYvzIfstUEoD4Od?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is a [scoped stylesheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style#A_scoped_stylesheet). Try adding the `scoped` attribute:

```
<style scoped>
    p {
        color: blue;
    } 
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this, but I am specifically talking about web components. Is there a way, using the web component technologies (templates, custom elements, shadow dom, html imports) to scope CSS? The scoped attribute is no longer supported by Chrome IIUC.